# How to use logical expressions in media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to create a rule that will fire styles if the device double width is bigger then device height **height < width * 2**. Is it possible to write such logical equations in media queries?

`@media only screen and (height < width * 2) {}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1)`?